# Configuration evaluation context not found warning on WCF trace

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a set of WCF services hosted on a .NET 4 application. I manually create the ServiceHost class and start listening on TCP port.
All works as expected but in the WCF trace on the server side I get the warning below.

**Configuration evaluation context not found.**

XML trace follows:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>524312</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-09-03T12:33:01.9404010Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="Server.Console.vshost" ProcessID="24612" ThreadID="10" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>BAROLO</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
                    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-IT/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Configuration evaluation context not found.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>Server.Console.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Any idea about the reason of the warning?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at that MSDN blog: [Missing Binding Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2009/07/29/missing-binding-extensions.aspx)?

> The evaluation context not found error (or in traces with the identifier System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound) is generally caused by using a configuration element defined in a library that is not included in the application’s configuration as an extension.

Comment: Yes I also see this post but I think to don't have any "configuration element defined in a library that is not included in the application’s configuration as an extension". I just use a custom service behavior (IServiceBehavior) configured directly by code and a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager. I don't use a configuration element (what is a configuration element?). Thanks!

Comment: Seems that WCF always try to look for a configuration element inside the application config file. When the configuration element doesn't exist throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is, you have to manually create service with service name and other details under  tag.

e.g.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
          <service name="WCF_NameSpace.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="behave">
              <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bind" contract="WCF_Trace_2.IService1"></endpoint>
          </service>
      </services>
```