# WCF 2-way ssl not working

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, ssl

I am a newbie to WCF. I have created a self hosted WCF server for the client is a java rest client. The communication between he client and the server should be mutually authenticated via ssl certificates at both ends. Therefore during communication, client needs to send the certificate. The client certificate needs to be custom validated on the server. 
I think the 1-way communication is happening fine but the server is not able to validate the client certificate. Actually the custom validator code is not executing itself.

In server traces, I see "configuration evaluation context not found" twice, guess there is some issue with the config file

My config file is as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="All, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\log\Traces.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <transactionFlow />
          <textMessageEncoding />
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
          <security authenticationMode="MutualSslNegotiated"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="myproject.MyX509CertificateValidator,myproject"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="myHost" behaviorConfiguration="behaviour">
        <endpoint address="" contract="IIWCFServer" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I already went through 100s of article but not able to get the solution. Any suggestion would be helpful.

The details of exception from the XML is as follows. Please let me know in case I can get the error details from any other place.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>524312</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
<Level>4</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-04-21T09:09:53.2168282Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{28fb55cc-1d5f-4a5a-a76e-5939a733b8f1}" />
<Execution ProcessName="testServer.vshost" ProcessID="2368" ThreadID="9" />
<Channel />
<Computer>WGP-PRINT-145</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Configuration evaluation context not found.</Description>
<AppDomain>testServer.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Could you include details of exception? refer [Configuration evaluation context not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636341/configuration-evaluation-context-not-found-warning-on-wcf-trace). Did you try giving the endpoint address in the config (as the mex endpoint requires a host base address)? Any reason why authenticationMode="MutualSslNegotiated" is used and not authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually, I am not very clear about the difference between authenticationMode="MutualCertificate/MutualCertificateDuplex/MutualSslNegotiated". I tried using the other options but got the same result.

Comment: How do you make the call to the WCF service?How do you add the certificate in the client side? Could you specify the client bindings, configuration etc? You could use tools like Fiddler or Soap UI to actually see the calls made to your service

Comment: The production environment will have java client, but currently for testing, I am using System.Net.HttpWebRequest class in c# to make request to the WCF server, I am adding the certificate to the client as  webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert).

Comment: I do not know how comfortable you would be with this, but you can easily use a WPF or Winforms client- Add the WCF service reference to it - Include the certificate in the config - Start TracingAndLogging in the client, and check whether the service is actually being called. The warnings that you mention usually happens  due to missing binding extensions. As of now I would recommend you to remove the mutual certificate requirement, see if the service works using basic configuration and then add these configurations step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me is as follows:

```
String port = 443;
String certificateSubject = "Mymachine";
String urlString = String.Format("https://{0}:{1}/",System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName, port);
Uri httpUrl = new Uri(urlString);
ServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(mynamespace.myclass), httpUrl);

WebHttpBinding wsBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
wsBinding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                                                    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                                    StoreName.My,
                                                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                                    certificateSubject);


host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new MyX509CertificateValidator();

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myinterface), wsBinding, httpUrl);
```